# How to load environment variables from AWS secret into CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

We are building a CI/CD pipeline in AWS CodePipeline with the goal of sourcing code from github, building a Docker image, testing the image and deploying it to a staging server.

Here is how our Build Stage looks like:

```
pre_build: 
    # Login to ECR 
    - f'$(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email) 

    # Get env variables from AWS Secret and write them to .env file 
    - secret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id project-env-variables --query SecretString --output text) 
    - echo "${secret}" | jq -r 'to_entries|map("(.key)=(.value|tostring)")|.[]' > ".env" 

build: 
    # Build docker image 
    - docker build -f Dockerfile.prod -t myproject:latest . 

    # Test application in docker image using .env file 
    - docker run --rm --env-file .env myproject:latest pytest 

post_build 
    # Uploading image to ECR
    - docker tag myproject:latest {repository_uri}:latest 
    - docker push {repository_uri}:latest
```

Is there a better way to load env variables to run our tests?

Is it okay to run the tests inside the (build) phase of Codebuild? Or should it be done somewhere else like a separate Stage or Action?

Answer (score 0):

AWS CodeBuild has built-in support for reading secrets from AWS Secrets Manager and SSM Parameter Store. You can see this in the build spec reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html). So you could replace this:

> secret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id project-env-variables --query SecretString --output text)

With this:

```
env:
  secrets-manager:
    secret: project-env-variables
```

It looks like you are ultimately needing those values to be in a `.env` file. I think you may still need to do something like you are now with the `echo` to pipe the values into the `.env` file. Although I don't see you using anything after that except `docker` which supports reading environment variables, in addition to `.env` files, so you may be able to streamline that by just setting environment variables.